# Is it possible to treat a zip file as a documentRoot in apache?

Tags: c, apache

I am trying to modify the apache source code in order to let it read the files inside a zip file instead of getting it directly from www folder.

example:

instead of having www/index.htm

I want to have a zip file that contains the index.htm

I've been working on this for days. Is it possible or I am just wasting my time?

Comment: What would be the point of doing this? Disk storage is so cheap now; wouldn't it be easier to just keep the data uncompressed?

Comment: There are several possibilities, including 1) writing your own Apache module, 2) Write a CGI to unzip/upload files on-the-fly, 3) mount [Fuse-Zip filesystem](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip) etc.  See this (duplicate):  [Make Apache virtual directory from the contents of a zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420295/make-apache-virtual-directory-from-the-contents-of-a-zip-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may indeed be wasting your time, but that doesn't mean it's not possible.  Apache certainly doesn't have any native capacity to treat a zipfile as a filesystem, but there are solutions you can pursue.

The simplest option would be to use something like [archivemount](https://github.com/bramp/archivemount) to expose the archive as a filesystem on the host.  This will let Apache -- and anything else -- treat it like a directory tree.